# Unable to get sudo to work in script when using cron

Tags: sudo, bash-scripting, cron

Environment: RHEL7.9
Access: No root access. I have sudo access to some commands (no password)
Issue: my personal crontab calls a script with sudo, sudo isn't working.

I have a script.sh that calls sudo /usr/systemctl start service, it works from my SHELL but not from crontab -e.

```
This works: [mike@host] $ sudo /usr/systemctl start service
This works: [mike@host] $ ./script.sh #which has the command it

This fails: [mike@host] $ crontab -e
#MQ CRONS
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/15 * * * * bash -l -c '/export/local/mike/script.sh >> /tmp/log.log'
```

In more detail, the script runs fine and does every step. When it gets to the sudo command it just doesn't do it or something. Any ideas? is there a cron limitation? I tried source /path/to/mike/.bash_profile in the script and some cron things to no avail. I turned on debug and it seems to just show the command be issued.

Comment: Possibly this: [*Why do I need a tty to run `sudo` if I can `sudo` without a password?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/108618)

Comment: Thanks I think you are on to something here. Sadly I can't try that because I don't have root, I will see where I can go with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was security:

I had an admin add the following to sudoers

```
Defaults !requiretty
```

More information can be seen here:
https://www.shell-tips.com/linux/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

this had occurred to me before and I had use the follow way to fix for my end. I'm not sure if it will fix it on your hand but give it a try.

Inside the script, remove the "sudo" command instead.

```
/usr/systemctl start service
```

when you enter the "crontab -e", insert a sudo at the front.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Inside the crontab, add a sudo infront of the bash.

```
*/15 * * * * sudo bash -l -c '/export/local/mike/script.sh >> /tmp/log.log'
```

My suspicion is that when the script is ran by cron, it is running with the user 'mike' and not root, thus it is not executing / failed to execute.

If it still don't work, you can provide the following logs so we can have more insights on what error you're facing

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Sorry, but this smells like [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), at least to some degree. `sudo crontab -e` edits root's crontab (the OP should be warned) and then `sudo` in front of `bash` is not needed. What's more important: the OP said "I have sudo access to some commands". I guess `sudo crontab -e` is *not* one of them. If it was, then the OP could run any command as root just by letting root's cron do this; this would render the restriction to "some commands" futile. We cannot count on admins leaving such a big hole for the OP.

Comment: I appricate the the response; sadly this won't work. The issue is that I have NO ability to sudo to anything but specific commands. If I were able to 'sudo crontab -e' then I could place the script in a root cron and and I wouldn't need to use sudo in the script at all since it is root user. Conversely I am using my own user's cron which needs the sudo in front of the systemctl command. Thanks for attempting to help though, I greatly appreciate it.